# How can I run ruby-espeak as root user?

Tags: ruby, text-to-speech, alsa

I am creating a ruby based application and I wish it to speak some text.  So far am using espeak:

```
fork{exec ("espeak 'New file located #{timelog.hour} #{timelog.min}' \" > /dev/null")}
```

which works when i run it as normal user, but I need this script to run as root.  When it runs as root I get:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
```

Why can't I run this script as root?
Also, is there another way to make my ruby script do TTS (Text To Speech)?

Added: I have even tried Festival when i run it nothing happens even as normal user.

```
require "rubygems"
require "festivaltts4r"
"I'm talking".to_speech
```

(gem list) ruby 1.9

```
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
clickatell (0.8.2)
espeak-ruby (0.4.0)
festivaltts4r (0.2.0)
ffi (1.1.5)
hoe (3.1.0)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
nice-ffi (0.4)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
ruby-sdl-ffi (0.4)
rubygame (2.6.4)
sms_fu (1.1.2)
tts (0.3.0)
```

OS:OpenSuse

Comment: the question is why are you going to run this script as root. pulseaudio is running in the user space. you should either run it for root, or much better run your script as user. if the script is detecting new files in the whole FS and is meant to say this aloud, there's nothing to stop you running it from your own user

Comment: Whether or not the script should be run as root, it is odd that the root user has trouble with alsa when the non-root user has no trouble.

Comment: my script requires root privileges its a basic script that alerts me on file change then scans it for signatures L1k3 an AntiVirus ;>

Comment: This may not be a Ruby problem.  Try running `espeak foo` and `sudo espeak foo` from the command line.  If you get the same problem, then I'd ask on one of the other stackexchange sites such as http://superuser.stackexchange.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution Run su Instead of sudo and it works ("espeak") that is
Thanks for all u'r help StackoverFlow Community ;>

Answer (score 1):

This trick is a bit cheesy, but it should work if you own a mac.

The make can say things from the command line with the 'say' command. Ergo;

```
$ say 'hello world'
```

Will have the computer say those words. This command can also be sent from Ruby via;

```
%x( say 'hello world' )
```

Comment: Or alternatively one can use https://rubygems.org/gems/mac-say (a gem I wrote some time ago) which does exactly the same, but allows you to use MacOS's say through Ruby interface :)